# Getting "Relay access denied" exception while try to send mail

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using Fake SMTP server to send mail and its working fine if I call the particular method from Main method. If I start the server and  all the same method from my application then I am getting

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 454 4.7.1 : Relay access denied

Comment: *Its working fine if I call the particular method from Main method* The `Main` method isn't part of your application?

Comment: No main method is not part of my application.I just simply tried from outside my application for testing purpose

Comment: See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#norelay).